# How to round a non-decimal value to nearest 100

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

This is in TradingView.

I tried match.ceil and math.round functions but it only takes the value to nearest integer but not 100.

Example: Value is 38796.65 I want that to be rounded to 38800
When I use round or ceil function it is just giving me an output of 38796

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In their [documentation](https://www.tradingcode.net/tradingview/round-to-hundreds/) they have an example function to round to hundreds as:

```
RoundToHundreds(value) =>
    math.round(value / 100.0) * 100
```

When using this would result in:

```
RoundToHundreds(102)       //  100
RoundToHundreds(190.95)    //  200
RoundToHundreds(983)       // 1000
RoundToHundreds(38796.65)  // 38800
```

Comment: You just need to make the function yourself and implement it.  Or can use the return statement as the implementation itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did see this but I was stupid enough to try "RoundToHundreds" as a function 

Comment: Glad to help! It happens to all of us